# ThreeJS: Rotate object to face another vector3

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have an array of Vector3 that will make up/draw a path.

From every point onwards I want to see which direction the next point will be. Straight or left or right if the angle is steep enough.

***What I tried***

I creating an Object3D on every vector of the array and then pointing that (with lookAt) to the next vector. But the rotation of the tempObject is NaN when I do.

I created two Object3D to get the second object's world position.

**What I expect**
I want to store the angle in radians or degrees of every Object3D to determine its direction.

```
const path = [
    { "x": -2.47, "y": 0, "z": 7.61 },
    { "x": -2.14, "y": 0, "z": 6.63 },
    { "x": -1.09, "y": 0, "z": 2.33 },
    { "x": -1.06, "y": 0, "z": 0.8 },
    { "x": -1.83, "y": 0, "z": 0.71 },
    { "x": -9.12, "y": 0, "z": 0.39 },
    { "x": -9.48, "y": 0, "z": -0.66 }
]; 

if (path.length > 2) {
   let index = 0;
   const pathSegments = Math.floor(path.length / 2);
   for (let i = 0; i<pathSegments; i++) {
      const v1 = path[index];
      const v2 = path[index+1];

      // Fake object
      const tempObject = new THREE.Object3D();
      tempObject.position.set(v1);
      tempObject.lookAt(v2);
      console.log(tempObject.rotation);
   }
}
```

I might be going about this the wrong way. Any help or points would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The objects in your `path` array have to be of type `THREE.Vector3`. Beside, `Vector3.set()` does not accept an instance of `THREE.Vector3` as an argument. So use the following or `THREE.Vector3.copy()`:

```js
tempObject.position.set(v1.x, v1.y, v1.z);
```

This should solve the NaN issue.

Comment: Thanks.. but they are Vector3, I copied the object from the Console, but it shows you they are Vector3s in the log. Also I use them to add spheres and lines in between.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Can you please refactor the way how you set the `position` property of `tempObject`?

Comment: Hi thanks alot, writing it out instead of the spread did work.

For anyone who is interested I added this example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-snowflake-4trvuq?file=/src/index.js